# Could not set unknown property 'enableR8' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.2, android-r8

i add this code in android studio 3.2;

```
  android.enableR8 = true
```

Could not set unknown property 'enableR8' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension
What does it mean ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade your project to Android-Studio-3.2 means 
 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` in Top-level gradle

then set property android.enableR8 = true into **`gradle.properties`**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

R8, the new code shrinker from Google, is available in Android studio still in beta version

R8 does all of shrinking, desugaring and dexing in one step. When comparing to the current code shrinking solution, Proguard, R8 shrinks the code faster while improving the output size.

Turn on R8 by default use below code in **gradle.properties**

org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -Xss4m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

**android.enableR8=true**

**android.enableR8.fullMode=true**